# Чем плох docker в docker?

Tags: docker

Я знаю кейс, когда нужен и очень помогает docker in docker:

- Запуск CI и изолированная сборка

Но чем плоха такая реализация и какие есть альтернативы изолированных сборок?

P.s. если вы приведёте ещё таких примеров, будет классно.

Comment: Агенты Azure DevOps и Github Actions работают в докере, и при этом отлично поддерживают докер внутри

Comment: @PashaPash я не говорю, что это нельзя использовать. Я говорю об отрицательных качествах решения.

Answer (score 1):

Я нашёл замечательную [статью](https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/). В целом, всё не так плохо, как я ожидал. Есть несколько основных проблем:

- Есть проблемы с модулями безопасности при работе на Fedora (для Ubuntu/Debian всё прекрасно)
- Вторая проблема связана с файловыми системами. Так, возникают проблемы с CoW-системами. При запуске такого рода систем, оказывается, что возникают side-эффекты. Например, при работе с AUFS поверх AUFS.
- В чистом виде отсутствует кэш сборки. Но эта проблема может быть относительно легко решена с помощью проброса сокета с хостовой машины. При этом не стоит забывать, что при одновременном использовании нескольких образов, могут возникнуть проблемы.
- Возникают проблемы с безопасностью. Но для этого есть решение [sysbox](https://github.com/nestybox/sysbox).